# Como colocar a função DataTable para todas as tabelas de uma vez

Tags: jquery-datatables

Eu gostaria de saber se eu consigo utilizar a função:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable ({
  scrolly: 300,
  paginação: false
});
```

Para todas as tabelas da minha pagina (de uma vez) ou se eu preciso configurar uma função para cada tabela da minha linha.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o seletor por tipo de elemento:

```
 $('table').DataTable ({ 
   scrolly: 300, 
   paging: false 
 });
```

Comment: O parametro de paginação não é `paginação` e sim `paging`.

Comment: Editei  @DiegoFelipe, obrigado, quis ser o meia simples possível e me passei.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possivel:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('table.display').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        scrolly: 300
      });
    })
```

Adicione uma `class` identica em todas as tabelas(no exemplo, seria `display`).

Sugiro que você dê uma olhada na documentação, lá tem exemplos de muitas funcionalidades do `datatable`.

Referencias:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html

https://datatables.net/manual/index